# SQL Server 2008R2 Cannot query linked Server

Tags: sql-server

I added a linked server by using SQL Server Management Studio and NT authentification (`sa`)

I can connect to the server and see databases but I cannot query anymore
The option to data access is set to True

So I don't know what's wrong

EDIT: This morning, after trying again i could execute a query!
So, i can't find why but it's work! \o/

Comment: `sa` is a **SQL Server** authentication - not **NT** authentication .....

Comment: cannot query? what is the error message?

Comment: Sorry @marc_s i confused ....

There is no error message, i just can't query. When i type "SELECT * FROM MyLinkedServer.MyBase.dbo.MyTable" I get Invalid object name error

Comment: I add another detail, in SQL Server Management Studio, when i right clic on a base or table, i don't have any entry for creating query or retrieve datas

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i get the issue because you write 'i cannot query anymore' as if you ever succeeded but if you expect to be able to right click on an object (table or view) accessible through a linked server and get the usual `SELECT TOP X` or `Edit top X` menu then you're out of luck: this is a feature that is not available on objects accessed through a linked server.

i just made a test on sql server version 2005, 2008 and 2012 using SSMS 2012 and 2005 and that right click menu is not available when on linked server.

Comment: my doubt is because of your last comment to the question where you write that you right click on a table. please add some code to the question to reproduce the issue and add the exact error message.